# How to filter out and group entries by row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = 
ID   GROUP_1  GROUP_2  GROUP_3  GRADE
1A   AAA      BBB      AAA      5
1B   BBB      BBB      CCC      4
1C   AAA      BBB      BBB      4
```

I want to count the number of rows with grades `5`, `4`, .., `1` for each unique value of `GROUP`. Please notice that in the row 1, there are 2 occurences of `AAA`, however I count it once.

The expected output for the given dataset is the following:

```
GROUP  GRADE_1   GRADE_2   GRADE_3   GRADE_4   GRADE_5
AAA    0         0         0         1         1
BBB    0         0         0         2         1
CCC    0         0         0         1         0
```

I have the below-given code and it works fine, excluding the grouping (`groupby('GRADE')`). I don't know how to group the results by `GRADE` and create columns `GRADE_1`, `GRADE_2`,...,`GRADE_5`.

```
df.groupby('GRADE').filter(regex="^GROUP").stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
   ID GROUP_1 GROUP_2 GROUP_3  GRADE
0  1A     AAA     BBB     AAA      5
1  1B     BBB     BBB     CCC      4
2  1C     AAA     BBB     BBB      4

In [57]: (df.set_index('GRADE')
    ...:    .filter(like='GROUP_')
    ...:    .stack()
    ...:    .to_frame('GROUP')
    ...:    .reset_index()
    ...:    .pivot_table(index='GROUP', columns='GRADE', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[57]:
GRADE  4  5
GROUP
AAA    1  2
BBB    4  1
CCC    1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Beause MaxU's answer is too good.  I had to work extra hard to contribute something useful.  This solution is meant to be fast(er) if less intuitive.

```
groups_df = df.filter(like='GROUP')
groups = groups_df.values.ravel().tolist()
grades = df.GRADE.values.repeat(len(groups_df.columns)).tolist()
s = pd.value_counts(list(zip(groups, grades)))
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    s.index.values.tolist(), names=['Group', 'GRADE'])

s.unstack(fill_value=0)

GRADE  4  5
Group      
AAA    1  2
BBB    4  1
CCC    1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first create columns containing True/False for each grade as follows:

```
for grade in df.GRADE.unique():
    col = 'GRADE_{}'.format(grade)
    df[col] = df.GRADE.apply(lambda x: x == grade)
```